# PHP Multidimensional Array Count

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array that I want to count the element of "PaymentType" == paypal. I am using this method 
$totalcount = `count(array_filter((array) $data[0], 'paypal'));`
but get the warning "'paypal', should be a valid callback"
Appreciate any response to help me get going in the right direction.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [TransactionDate] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [TotalAmount] => 0.00
        [PayPalFee] => 2.48
        [PayPalTransactionID] => 92
        [PaymentType] => paypal
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [TransactionDate] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        [TotalAmount] => 0.00
        [PayPalFee] => 2.48
        [PayPalTransactionID] => 3
        [PaymentType] => paypal
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [TransactionDate] => 2011-05-16 11:15:02
        [TotalAmount] => 75.00
        [PayPalFee] => 2.48
        [PayPalTransactionID] => 2
        [PaymentType] => paypal
    )
)
```

Comment: `array_filter` takes a **callback** as second argument, as described in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php. There you will also find examples on how to use `array_filter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_filter()` is supposed to return a filtered array (and also needs a callback function to work, not a search value) - you don't need to do that. Here's a solution that really only counts the matches:

```
$totalcount = 0;
for ($i = 0, $c = count($data[0]); $i < $c; $i++)
{
    if ($data[0][$i]['PaymentType'] === 'paypal')
        $totalcount++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) requires a callback for the 2nd argument.  You have to write a custom function to filter out only the results you want, like below:

```
$totalcount = count(array_filter($data, function($arr)
{
    return $arr['PaymentType'] == 'paypal';
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your filter needs a little work:

```
array_filter($data, function ($datum) { return $datum['paymentType'] == 'paypal'; })
```